# Don't have Stack Overflow propose that I vote in the moderator election when I don't have the reputation to do so

Tags: discussion, reputation, notifications, election

A Stack Overflow notification is suggesting that I "*Cast [my] vote in the Stack Overflow 2011 community moderator primary!*" But I don't have enough reputation to do so. I don't want to see advertisements for something I can't even do.

Edit: Just play the game.

Comment: I feel the same way every time I see a Mercedes ad. :)

Comment: @Pekka: but have you actually *tried* showing your SO rep to your local Mercedes dealer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. It might be is useful for you to know that community moderators are elected
2. It might be incentive for you to get your reputation up so that you can vote (especially if you are just under the cutoff.
3. There are faqs and other text and links on SO that talk about and encourage things that are only available to those with reputation to allow it.

Comment: "Get the reputation" In my own opinion, if you are not a guru in StackOveflow, you can hardly have hundred of reps. I find that it's easier to tweak with a friend or 2 and fire Q-A at each others. I don't want to do that. Anyway, IMOO..

Comment: I just find that reputation seems to my like achievment in gaming. People play game for the achievment and not for the fun of it. In SO, people seems to answer/comment for Reps. not to help people.

Comment: @Philippe, there might be people that are just on SO for the rep, but please don't generalize that to everyone here.  There are many people that want to truly want help others out for a variety of reasons other than rep.

Comment: @jzd You mean .. badges? :)

Comment: "People are here only for the rep, not to help" is  as impossible to prove or disprove as is "People become doctors only for the money, not to help" - for some, it's true, for some, it's not. But you can always make the accusation, and nobody will be able to contradict you.

Comment: @belisarius ahahahaha!

Comment: @All, you are all right guys (and girls?). I guess I just have to play the game.

Answer (score 1):

So don't vote (obviously). The reasoning could be to promote a sense of wanting which will cause you to work and earn the rep so you could vote next time.

Comment: Nahhh that kind of desire should appeal to lower instincts than voting :)